# Return a subset of array where a given field is present

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I would like to filter the `Categories` embedded Array to get only those which have a `parent` key.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5737283639533c000978ae71"),
    "name": "Swiss",
    "Categories": [
        {
            "name": "Management",
            "_id": ObjectId("5738982e39533c00070f6a53")
        },
        {
            "name": "Relations",
            "_id": ObjectId("5738984a39533c000978ae72"),
            "parent": ObjectId("5738982e39533c00070f6a53")
        },
        {
            "name": "Ambiance",
            "_id": ObjectId("57389bed39533c000b148164")
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried with the `find` but without success.
After some research it seems that it can be done via the aggregation command but I don't like the way it works, I would prefer to use only the find command.

Also, I'm asking myself if in term of performances it wouldn't be better to store each Categories in a new collection, would it be ?

Edit, I would like to get something like this as find output :

```
    [
        {
            "name": "Relations",
            "_id": ObjectId("5738984a39533c000978ae72"),
            "parent": ObjectId("5738982e39533c00070f6a53")
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way to do is in MongoDB 3.2 using the aggregation framework.  All you need is project your documents and use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to return a subset of the "Categories" array that match your criteria, but to do this you will need to use [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator give a "default" value to the "parent" field in all those sub-documents where that field is missing then use the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) in your `cond` expression which determine where a give element should be included in the subset.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "Categories": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$Categories", 
                "as": "catg", 
                "cond": { 
                    "$ne": [
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$$catg.parent", false ] }, 
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

---

From version 3.0 backwards, you need a different approach. Instead you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to return a give element if it matches your criteria or `false` then use the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator to filter out all those element in the returned array which are equal to `false`. Of course `$setDifference` is fine as long as the data being filtered is "unique".

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "Categories": { 
            "$setDifference": [ 
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": "$Categories", 
                    "as": "catg", 
                    "in": { 
                         "$cond": [ 
                             { "$ne": [
                                 { "$ifNull": [ "$$catg.parent", false ] },
                                 false
                             ]}, 
                             "$$catg", 
                             false
                        ]}
                    }
                }, 
                [ false ] 
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

#### Translation in PHP gives:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    array(
        array("$project" => array(
            "_id" => 0, 
            "Categories" => array( 
                "$filter" => array(
                    "input" => "$Categories", 
                    "as" => "catg", 
                    "cond" => array(
                         "$ne" => array(
                             array("$ifNull" => array("$$catg.parent", false), 
                         false
                    )
                )
              )  
          )
      ))
   )
)
```

And something this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    array(
        array("$project" => array( 
            "_id" => 0, 
            "Categories" => array( 
                "$setDifference" => array(
                    "$map" => array( 
                        "input" => "$Categories", 
                        "as" => "catg", 
                        "in" => array( 
                            "$cond" => array(
                                "$ne" => array(
                                     array("$ifNull" => array( "$$catg.parent", false ) ),
                                     false
                            ), 
                            "$$catg", 
                            false
                        )
                    ),
                    array(false) 
                )
            )
        ))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a solution according to above mentioned description please try executing following query

```
db.mycoll.find({Categories:{$elemMatch:{parent:{$exists:true}}}},

{Categories:{$elemMatch:{parent:{$exists:true}}}})
```

The above example uses [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to filter elements in an embedded document.

Comment: Yes but I get the whole document instead of just the parts I want. I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: You can't use projection with `$elemMatch` here, as it will only return the first match in the array.